# Running an express server on a machine

Tags: express

I have a machine to which I can SSH. I have installed the express and other relevant node_modules. I have written a basic server code for "Hello World".

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sed("Hello World!");
});
app.listen(8XXX, "172.XX.XXX.XXX");
```

However, i get the following error.

```
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 172.28.120.107:5559
```

I have already sshed to my mahcine. Should i be giving the IP address as "127.0.0.1" in the server code.
Very new to this . Thanks

Comment: I think you must listen to localhost wich is as you already mentioned 127.0.0.1

Comment: @JavaEvgen  how do i access this code in a browser...Thanks!

Comment: Simply by writing 127.0.0.1:8xxx(your port) in your browser if you are "inside" the local host machine or the machine internal ip(starting with 192.168.) if you are on the same network, or 172.28.120.107:5559 if you have forwarded the port you assign on a router of the machine the app is hosted